# How to clean up output from Laravel collection

Tags: laravel

Long story short:

I need to extract from the database, a **Clean**, nested list of categories in some specific format (id, name and array of children, to use with this package https://vue-treeselect.js.org/)

I'm making my queries like:

```php
    $expense_categories  = ExpenseCategory::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get(['id', 'name']);
    $expense_categories->toJson();
```

and I don't know how to get rid of all the extra stuff Laravel throws out at me:

[image]

I have also tried:

```php
$expense_categories->toArray();
```

Comment: Why you are not using Eloquent Api resource to format your data before sending it to client side?

Comment: Laravel **doesn't** throw all that out if you do `toJson()` - the output you've shown is what happens if you do something like `dd()` on the model, to dump its internal data. Please detail the actual problem you're having.

Comment: I guess I've just never done it before. Is that the right way to do it? I really though it's just some small thing I'm missing here.

Comment: @ceejayoz, actually if I'll just use the basic PHP function `var_dump($expense_categories);`, I'll pretty much get all of those extra things, only in a not so nice formated way. I want just an array of `id` and `name` pairs with the extra `children` array.

Comment: You should read https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Already on it. I though there is maybe some small thing I'm missing. As 99 percent of the times you only need the actual data from the collection output.

Comment: I see that the `Eloquent API resources` were added in version 5.5, how about getting similar functionalities prior to version 5.5 ?

Comment: @AngelinCalu Something like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal would suit pre-5.5 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this as someone else might stumble upon it sometime in the future.

As suggested in the comments, one good way to do it before Laravel 5.5 would be to use a package like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal.

After Laravel 5.5, https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources would be the preferred way to do it, however, `laravel-fractal` would still work.